# Architectural design of a Heroku application with Ember.js, Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, ember.js

I'm starting to implement a Heroku application based on Ember (frontend), Node and Express (backend).

I'm thinking to segregate the frontend and the backend in different apps. Both apps will be secured by Auth0.

What do you think about it? I'm on the right way?

Comment: It depends on what you call an app I guess.

Comment: Hi @TGrif! Heroku is a PaaS that enables to run services as apps (it's a way they call a deployable). My question is about what is the _best practice_ in the cited scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think you're going about it the right way. My company has a Ruby on Rails backend and EmberJS frontend. We have the backend as one heroku app, and the frontend as another heroku app. For ember, we use [Ember CLI Deploy](http://ember-cli-deploy.com/) to deploy to production on Heroku.

Comment: Nice @Tyler! I'll do that! Thank you so much for the support!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that’s generally the preferred way to build Ember apps. We built the api viewer in this manner to have a reference app that works on Heroku with Fastboot that people could look at: https://github.com/ember-learn/ember-api-docs